# mySQL query - find where points are?

Tags: mysql, find, where-clause

let's say, this is my DB structure:

```
id, group_name, points_needed;
```

and these are sample records:

```
1, "Newbie", 0,
2, "Amatour", 100,
3, "Expert", 500,
4, "Pro", 100;
```

However, I don't know how to find the group_name that fits to my current points. Let's say I've 120 rank points. So as with example above, I should have tag "Amatour". However, how can I find this tag in my db? ([b]mysql[/b]).

I though to use WHERE and to group it, but if I would look for greater value, I would miss "Amatour" record. If I would look for smaller value, I would get this record, but this have to be dynamic query, so if I would have 100 points and I would look for smaller value, I wouldn't find it. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT group_name
FROM `YouDidn'tNameThisTable`
WHERE points_needed <= ?
ORDER BY points_needed DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hello, I guess `points_needed <= ?` is right. e.g someone who has 0 point belongs to Newbie group.

Comment: @InoSHeo, thanks, that's a good point. I have edited the above to include that.

Answer (score 1):

Select * from table where points_needed <= 120 order by points_needed limit 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use <= operator and use a limit operator to limit the select query to one record .

Select group_name from yourtable_name where points_needed <= your_points order by points_needed DESC limit 1

Comment: Replace the yourtable_name with your table name and your_points with the points for which you want to find the group name.. for eg: Assuming your table name is "ranktable" and you have got 480 points , then the query would be Select group_name from ranktable where points_needed <= 480 order by points_needed limit 1

Comment: Edit: you need the descending keyword DESC to make sure that the records are ordered in the descending order to find the right rank that will match your criteria : So the query would be " Select group_name from ranktable where points_needed <= 480 order by points_needed desc limit 1"

Answer (score 0):

if you want latest record then:

```
SELECT group_name FROM <tableneme> WHERE points_needed <=120 
ORDER BY points_needed DESC LIMIT 1
```

if you want old record then:

```
 SELECT group_name FROM <tableneme> WHERE points_needed <=120 
 ORDER BY points_needed ASC LIMIT 1
```